# How to display a component only on ipad using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i want to display an icon in the component for ipad device. And dont display icon in the component for others.

I am new to developing code for ipads / mobile devices. i am not sure how to do the above for ipad device.

below is my code,

```
function Navbar() {
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <div>
                <LogoLink to="/">
                    <span>Title</span>
                </LogoLink>
            </div>

            <div>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/items" component={ComponentOne} />
                       <Route
                           exact
                           path="/items"
                           render={() => (
                           <span>Title</span>
                       )}
                   />
               </Switch>
           </div>
   
           <div>
               <Route path="/items/:id" component={Somecomponent} />
               <Icon /> //should display this icon only on ipad.
           </div>
       </Wrapper>
   );
```

}

export default Navbar;

Could someone let me know how to do it using react and typescript. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do something like:

```
window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().includes('ipad')
```